# Automatically Register App after Startup in Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

i am using Spring Cloud Dataflow in Kubernetes. Basically i only register a Spring Batch Job that is then triggered by an integration test later. I need this app to be registered straight after the deployment.

I have multiple namespaces, so multiple SCDF instances and thus multiple Ingresses for SCDF.
Instead of registering the app on SCDF manually, i am currently doing it by using the REST API after the deployment.

As there are like 5 different namespaces and 5 different domains of SCDF accordingly, i want to simply this a bit. Ideally, the app gets registered by SCDF configuration out of the box so the app registers the app itself as soon as the app runs. Something like a "default app" or something.

Do you know if there is a possibility to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Java program to register your application using the [DataFlowTemplate](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/rest/client/DataFlowTemplate.java) or you can write a CLI script using [Dataflow Shell](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/concepts/tooling/#shell), or directly over http using something like curl.